# PHP: Count the appearance of particular value in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am wondering if I could explain this.

I have a multidimensional array , I would like to get the count of particular value appearing in that array

Below I am showing the snippet of array . I am just checking with the **profile_type** .

So I am trying to display the count of **profile_type** in the array

**EDIT**

Sorry I've forgot mention something, not something its the main thing , I need the count of **profile_type==p**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Driver] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [profile_type] => p                    
                    [birthyear] => 1978
                    [is_elite] => 0
                )
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [Driver] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [profile_type] => d                    
                    [birthyear] => 1972
                    [is_elite] => 1
                )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution with [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator), so you don't have to care about the dimensions:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

$counter = 0
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == 'profile_type' && $value == 'p') {
    $counter++;
  }
}
echo $counter;
```

Comment: Sorry I've edited the question I need count of the profile_type==p

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work...

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    foreach ($innerArray as $driver=>$arr) {
        $counts[] = $arr['profile_type']; 
    }
}

$solution = array_count_values($counts);
```

Comment: Sorry I've edited the question I need count of the profile_type==p

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
$profile = array();
foreach($array as $elem) {
    if (isset($elem['Driver']['profile_type'])) {
        $profile[$elem['Driver']['profile_type']]++;
    } else {
        $profile[$elem['Driver']['profile_type']] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use array_walk($array,"test")  and define a function "test" that checks each item of the array for 'type' and calls recursively array_walk($arrayElement,"test") for items of type 'array' , else checks for the condition. If condition satisfies, increment a count.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can get count of profuke_type==p  from a multi dimensiona array

```
    $arr = array();
    $arr[0]['Driver']['id'] = 4;
    $arr[0]['Driver']['profile_type'] = 'p';
    $arr[0]['Driver']['birthyear'] = 1978;
    $arr[0]['Driver']['is_elite'] = 0;


    $arr[1]['Driver']['id'] = 4;
    $arr[1]['Driver']['profile_type'] = 'd';
    $arr[1]['Driver']['birthyear'] = 1972;
    $arr[1]['Driver']['is_elite'] = 1;

    $arr[2]['profile_type'] = 'p';
    $result = 0;
    get_count($arr, 'profile_type', 'd' , $result);
    echo $result;
    function get_count($array, $key, $value , &$result){
        if(!is_array($array)){
            return;
        }

        if($array[$key] == $value){
            $result++;
        }

        foreach($array AS $arr){
            get_count($arr, $key, $value , $result);
        }
    }
```

try this..

thanks